# Intersection of two rectangles with NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cython

I have the following function to find the intersection of two rectangles. It's a little bit slow, I don't know if it's due to the `OR` condition or the `>, <` operators. I wonder if there's a way to improve the performance of the `is_intersect()` function. Maybe with NumPy? Or Cython?

```
import numpy as np

def is_intersect(rect1, rect2):
    xmin1, xmax1, ymin1, ymax1 = rect1
    xmin2, xmax2, ymin2, ymax2 = rect2
    if xmin1 > xmax2 or xmax1 < xmin2:
        return False
    if ymin1 > ymax2 or ymax1 < ymax2:
        return False
    return True

N_ELEMS = 100000000
rects1 = np.random.rand(N_ELEMS,4)
rects2 = np.random.rand(N_ELEMS,4)

temp_dct = dict()

for i in range(N_ELEMS):
    rect1 = rects1[i,:]
    rect2 = rects2[i,:]
    if is_intersect(rect1, rect2):
        temp_dct[i] = True
```

I can't profit from caching results as the points will be incremental, that is, one rectangle will move in space (never the same place). In this example, I used NumPy's `random()` function, but that's not the case for my real use. I will call the `is_intersect()` function 100 000 000 times or more.

Comment: Are you sure `is_intersect()` is correct? As `rects1` is random, `xmin1` may greater than `xmax1`. For example, `is_intersect([0.5,0.1,0.2,0.5], [0.3,0.6,0.4,0.6])` return `False` but they are intersect.

Comment: xmin1 will never be greather than xmax1. The random was a poor choice of example. In my case xmax1 is always greater than xmin1.

Comment: Fixed the typo `ymax1 < ymax1`. Also edited my solution for speed up

Comment: you can try shapely package https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersects

Comment: @AlyHosny I did, but shapely is awfully slow. Or I did use it incorrectly.

Comment: @AlyHosny I just made a comparison between FBruzzesi implementation and Shapely. Shapely is taking more than 1h to finish while FBruzzesi's solution took 14s. I'm not using the example given in the question, I'm testing with my data, which is a little bit different. Shapely is much more readable but I can't afford to wait for more than 1h for such a simple task. But again, I may be using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve performance by avoiding the for loop using vectorized comparison and `np.any`:

```py
result = (1 - np.any([rects1[:,0] > rects2[:,1], 
                      rects1[:,1] < rects2[:,0], 
                      rects1[:,2] > rects2[:,3], 
                      rects1[:,3] < rects2[:,2]], 
                     axis=0)).astype(bool)
```

You don't get a dictionary, yet you can access `result` by index.

Performance with 100M elements:

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

N_ELEMS = 100_000_000
rects1 = np.random.rand(N_ELEMS,4)
rects2 = np.random.rand(N_ELEMS,4)

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
result = (1 - np.any([rects1[:,0] > rects2[:,1], 
                      rects1[:,1] < rects2[:,0], 
                      rects1[:,2] > rects2[:,3], 
                      rects1[:,3] < rects2[:,2]], 
                     axis=0)).astype(bool)

print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
2.9162093999999996
```